# How to make Google display only Country-specific search results based on user's location

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, web-crawlers, geolocation

My question goes like this:

I own a multinational company with the following websites

```
www.abc.com/us/
www.abc.com/uk/
www.abc.com/apac/
```

I advertise my product (let's name it "device") on each of my above regional websites like

```
www.abc.com/us/device/
www.abc.com/uk/device/
www.abc.com/apac/device/
```

Content on the above webpages is almost the same albeit some minor differences.

When a user from US searches "device" using Google Search, Google Search result returns all the above three URLs

```
www.abc.com/us/device
www.abc.com/uk/device
www.abc.com/apac/device
```

I do not want this to happen as it confuses the user and would want Google to display only www.abc.com/us/device for the US user in his search results,www.abc.com/uk/ for the UK user and so on.

What changes do I need to make on my webpage source for Google to display only my United States website (www.abc.com/us/device) in the search results (for US user)

Comment: Google allows geo-targeting on a country by country basis.   Your US and UK directories should be doable, but you will need to split your APAC directory up into each country within the Asia Pacific region that you want to target.

Answer (score 2):

For Google specifically, you can set up Search Console geotargeting under Search Traffic > International Targeting. Check the box and select "unlisted" so Google will become aware that you are targeting multiple countries.

From there, Google explains 3 ways to set the country and language combination:

- Use an hreflang tag - this really works best for pure translations, rather than country by country targeting
- Submit sitemaps - you can specify which portions of your site target which countries
- Headers - similar to an hreflang tag, these are mainly for translations

You can see their help at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?hl=en. However, if you really need unique content on a country by country basis, I think you would do better for both human visitors and search engines if you moved out of subfolders and toward subdomains. So you would have

`www.example.com/device` - for the U.S.

`uk.example.com/device` - for the U.K.

`apac.example.com/device` - for APAC

This is a much clearer signal and segregation of what content is for what users, and by setting up subdomains you can also more easily have custom navigation that stays within that same subdomain. You can have the `www.example.com` homepage display a country selection, then take people off to their respective country subdomain as needed.